# Conditional color of countries selecting word in name of Topojson

Tags: d3.js, include, conditional-statements, indexof, topojson

I have made maps in D3 and I have conditionally assigned colors on id's and properties before. In this case I am trying to color conditionally depending on the presence of a specific word in the name. For example: color blue all countries with the word "United" in their names, all other countries  pink. In this case it would color "United States", "United Kingdom", and "United Arab Emirates" blue. 
I have tried indexOf and some and str.includes but it results in: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/databayou/retk2pu6/7/

```
  svg.selectAll(".country")
  .data(topojson.feature(nations, nations.objects.countries).features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "country " + d.name; })
  .attr("fill",function(d){ 
          var str = d.name;
          if (str.includes("United")) { return "blue"}
                            else {return "pink";
                           }
                       })
  .attr("d", path);
```

Comment: `var str = d.name;` is assigning `undefined` to `str`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var str = d.name;` to `var str = d.properties.name;`

If you console.log `d`, you will see that `name` is inside of `properties`.